# Combining related information within a cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

[image: node-relationship schema]

I have created a knowledge with the nodes and relationships pictured. Each person has any number of jobs and skills connected to them and each Job and Skill can have any number of People connected to them. I would like to be able to search for a particular job (e.g. Security Architect) and return a list of all the people who have been employed_as that job and all of the skills that each person is skilled_in. I have created a query hich retrieves these results, however a new line in the query is created for each skill, duplicating the person details each time. This is the query I have which retrieves those results.

```
MATCH (j:Job {job_title: "Security Architect"})<-[p_rel:employed_as]-(p:Person)-[skilled_in]->(s:Skill) return p,s,p_rel
```

Is it possible to create a query that returns all of the skill nodes connected to a person as a single list with the details of that person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need all skills in single line, you can collect all the skills per person.

```
MATCH (j:Job {job_title: "Security Architect"})<-[p_rel:employed_as]-(p:Person)
-[skilled_in]->(s:Skill) 
RETURN p,p_rel, collect(s) as skills_per_person
```